# Convert SQL to LINQ JOIN/GROUP BY/COUNT/DISTINCT

Tags: sql, linq

I got a rather tough query to convert from SQL to LINQ-to-Entities.
Here's my SQL code:

```
select c_id
from db.c 
inner join db.i on c_id = i_c
inner join db.l on c_id = l_c
group by c_id
having count(distinct i_attributeX) > count(distinct l_attributeY)
```

I seem to have problems with the distinct in linq. Any suggestions?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this:

```
var result = db.c
    .Where(c => 
        c.i.Select(i => i.attributeX).Distinct().Count() >
        c.l.Select(l => l.attributeY).Distinct().Count()
    ) 
    .Select(c => c.id);
```

or alternatively

```
var result = db.c
    .Where(c => 
        c.i.GroupBy(i => i.attributeX).Count() >
        c.l.GroupBy(l => l.attributeY).Count()
    ) 
    .Select(c => c.id);
```

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks a ton! I was suspecting that a lambda expression would be the solutions. I was trying to do it with SQL-like query syntax.